# Flex4: if I want different icons, should I create a skin class for each button?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

i have a sequence of buttons and each button has its own icon.
I was wondering if I have to create a Spark skin file for each button in order to assign its icon.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create separate skins, you could make 1 skin and 1 class (that extends `Button`) with a property you can set to determine which icon to draw based on the button.

You can extend the button class like this

```
package com.components
{
    import spark.components.Button;     

    //icons
    [Style(name="iconImg",type="*")]

    public class IconButton extends Button
    {
        public function IconButton()
        {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

At this point you'd have a set of `IconButton`s and you'd need to set the `iconImg` property for each.

Declare the icon

```
[Embed('assets/bookmarkIcon.png')]
public static const icon_bookmark:Class;
```

And the set the `iconImg` property

```
<components:IconButton id="ibBookmark"
               iconImg="{icon_bookmark}"
               skinClass="com.skins.IconButtonSkin"                        
               click="" />
```

Then in your skin you use the property like this

```
<mx:Image id="icon" source="{hostComponent.getStyle('iconImg')}"  />
```

Comment: thanks, is this solution working for over and up states as well ?

Comment: Np -- yeah, you can add as many style tags in the IconButton class as you need and then in the skin assign the different sources by state