# different icons for the same Button skin flex

Tags: apache-flex, button, icons, skin

I have the skin below for my buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:SparkSkin 
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo"
>
<!-- host component -->
<fx:Metadata>
    <![CDATA[
    [HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]
    ]]>
</fx:Metadata>  

<!-- states -->
<s:states>
    <s:State name="up" />
    <s:State name="over" stateGroups="overStates"/>
    <s:State name="down" stateGroups="overStates" />
    <s:State name="disabled" />
</s:states>

.....
 </s:SparkSkin>
```

I was wondering how I can add a different image for different buttons which have the same skin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps:

1. Have your custom Skin extend [SparkButtonSkin](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/skins/SparkButtonSkin.html) instead of simply
   SparkSkin.
2. Set the `icon` style of your Button

---

```
 <s:Button icon="@Embed('/path/to/my-icon.png')" 
           skinClass="path.to.MyButtonSkin" />
```

Comment: and a 3rd which appears here:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974518/flex4-if-i-want-different-icons-should-i-create-a-skin-class-for-each-button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974518/flex4-if-i-want-different-icons-should-i-create-a-skin-class-for-each-button)

Comment: @sstauross Since Flex 4.5 the default Button has icon suppart built-in. It is no longer necessary to create a custom class for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the path of the image (the full path or relative to the path you are in)

```
<s:Button label="Spark Button with dynamic icon" icon="assets/asterisk_orange.png" />
```

Or embed the image

```
<s:Button label="Spark Button with inline embedded icon" icon="@Embed('assets/asterisk_orange.png')" />
```